# Randomly display images on the screen(JFrame)

Tags: java, awt

As you already know everything I started writing little game about space.

"Not a bad start" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818655/simulation-of-spaceplanets-and-stars :D

I wrote a little plan of the work, and the first point in that it is' Random generation of stars.
You could say, easier use the random.

```
Random random = new Random();
int x = random.nextInt(getWidth()*2);
int y = random.nextInt(getHeight()*2);
g.drawImage(Image,x,y,4,4,this);
```

But it does not work (

And it is not working because the pictures "jump" on the screen.

As to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EELo_-eh3fA

So how do you randomly bring the stars? (Star is a small picture or a white square)
That's all the code:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Game extends JComponent {

    public Game() {
     try {
       image  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("star.png"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        repaint();

        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(getWidth()*2);
        int y = random.nextInt(getHeight()*2);
        g.drawImage(Image,x,y,4,4,this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(NAME);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.add(new Game());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.addMouseListener(mos);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(mos);
    }
}
```

Here's a code does not work ( 
Pictures jump again.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        repaint();
        Random random = new Random();
        int x = random.nextInt(getWidth()*2);
        int y = random.nextInt(getHeight()*2);
        g.drawImage(kor,x,y,10,10,this);
}
```

@camickr, You said to remove repaint(); but without it I do not get a picture

Comment: How to fix the picture? that they did not jump.

Comment: *"You said to remove repaint(); but without it I do not get a picture"* You need to have an outside loop somewhere that calls repaint. You need to start a new Thread that does it. Also I don't understand what you mean by "jump". You are drawing circles at random points and painting them and that's what the screen captures shows.

Comment: You don't need an outside loop to call repaint(). You call repaint when you change a property of the component. For example if you change the x/y values, or if you add a new image to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method not the paint() method.
2. Never invoke repaint() in a painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.

> How to fix the picture? that they did not jump.

Basically the location needs to be determined outside of the painting method.

Maybe you can start with [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) to get the idea of painting multiple objects on a panel. I would suggest the first approach of adding objects to a List. So you would add multiple objects to the list, but each object would be given a random location.

> You said to remove repaint(); but without it I do not get a picture

Did you take the time to look at the link I gave you? The examples show you when to do a repaint().